# Creating a parameter filter to pick out consecutive data (Tableau Desktop)

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I have a data set as following:

| week number | date | item | location | Out of stock % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | 2022-06-05 | apple | Seattle | 55% |
| 23 | 2022-06-06 | apple | Seattle | 60% |
| 23 | 2022-06-07 | apple | Seattle | 50% |
| 23 | 2022-06-08 | apple | Seattle | 50% |
| 23 | 2022-06-09 | apple | Seattle | 50% |
| 23 | 2022-06-10 | apple | Seattle | 50% |
| 23 | 2022-06-11 | apple | Seattle | 60% |
| 23 | 2022-06-06 | orange | California | 10% |
| 23 | 2022-06-07 | orange | California | 5% |
| 23 | 2022-06-08 | orange | California | 5% |
| 23 | 2022-06-09 | orange | California | 30% |
| 23 | 2022-06-06 | orange | California | 20% |
| 23 | 2022-06-07 | orange | California | 10% |
| 23 | 2022-06-08 | orange | California | 2% |

My desired output is to have an Out of stock filter for the viewers so that when they enter a certain value, it returns a list of a certain week in which the out of stock is no lesser than the certain value.

For example, if I enter 40% in the filter, then apple at Seattle would only show up.
This apple would be then marked as continuously out of stock. Please help me!